# running Laravel docker image with database service

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-container, docker-run

I have a dockerized Laravel project that I am trying to move to production but I don't know how to run the image establishing connection to the database. Every time I ran the image I received this message because I can't connect to the database.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

What should I do to run correctly an image connecting to the database. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
  version: "3.6"
  services:
    app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./setup/Dockerfile
      container_name: simple2_web
      restart: unless-stopped
      tty: true
      ports:
        - "${APP_PORT}:80"
      env_file:
        - ./setup/.env
      working_dir: /var/www/simple
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/simple
      networks:
        - esnet
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
        - elasticsearch
    db:
      image: "mysql:5.7"
      container_name: simple2_db
      command: ["--sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"]
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
        - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
      restart: unless-stopped
      networks:
        - esnet
    redis:
      image: "redis"
      container_name: simple2_redis
      networks:
        - esnet
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      depends_on:
        - db
    elasticsearch:
      image: "elasticsearch:5.6"
      container_name: simple2_elastic
      environment:
        - discovery.type=single-node
      volumes:
        - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - "${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}:9200"
      networks:
        - esnet
      depends_on:
        - db
    rabbitmq:
      image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
      container_name: simple2_rabbit
      hostname: "simple_rabbit"
      environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
        RABBITMQ_QUEUE: ${RABBITMQ_QUEUE}
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
        DOWNLOADS_MAX_JOBS_PER_USER: ${DOWNLOADS_MAX_JOBS_PER_USER}
      ports:
        - "${RABBITMQ_PORT_MANAGER}:15672"
        - "${RABBITMQ_PORT}:5672"
      volumes:
        - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
        - rabbitmq_logs:/var/log/rabbitmq
      networks:
        - esnet

  #Docker Volumes
  volumes:
    db_data:
    elasticsearch_data:
    rabbitmq_data:
    rabbitmq_logs:

  #Docker Networks
  networks:
    esnet:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Comment: Not too many details on how to help you - can you please add more details or code?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert done